# Angular 6 + Bootstrap 4 add "show" class with @HostBinding

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular6

```
@Directive({selector: '[appDropdown]'})

export class DropdownDirective {

  @HostBinding('class.show') isShowing = false;

  @HostListener('click') toggleShow() {
    this.isShowing = !this.isShowing;
  }
}
```

[...]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="btn-group" appDropdown role="group" aria-label="Button group 
     with nested dropdown">                                       
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button id="btnGroupDrop1" 
                    appDropdown
                    type="button" 
                    class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" 
                    data-toggle="dropdown" 
                    aria-haspopup="true" 
                    aria-expanded="false">
              Manage Recipe
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" appDropdown>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Shopping List</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit Recipe</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete Recipe</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hello!

I'm currently learning Angular 6 but I have a problem which I just can't understand.
With HostBinding and HostListener I add the class "show" in different parts of my html.
The first two are working fine, and the class "show" is added here after clicking the responsible button:

```
<div class="btn-group" appDropdown role="group" [...]

<button id="btnGroupDrop1" appDropdown [...]
```

But not on the third one, which actually matters, because only there the dropdown menu will show.
Here

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" appDropdown>
```

the show-class will not be added and I don't understand why. I used Chromes inspection tool and while the first two get changed, the third doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code

```
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" appDropdown>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

add add these cdn in your index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: before the a tag add  <div class="dropdown"> and add jquery cdn as well in your index.html

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngClass` to resolve this problem instead of using `directive`

In template file

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button
      class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
      [ngClass]="{'show': isShow}"
      type="button"
      (click)="onToggle()"
    >
      Options<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu"
    [ngClass]="{'show': isShow}">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In ***.ts*** file

```
  isShow = false;

  onToggle() {
    this.isShow = !this.isShow;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to using `directive` you can use

Template file

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" toggleDropDown>
      Options<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Directive file

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[toggleDropDown]'
})
export class DropDownDirective {

    private isShow = false;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}


    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) toggleShow(event: Event) {
        const buttonGroup = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        const dropdownMenu = this.elementRef.nativeElement.nextSibling;

        if (buttonGroup.contains(event.target)) {
            this.isShow = true;
            this.renderer.addClass(dropdownMenu, 'show');
        } else {
            this.isShow = false;
            this.renderer.removeClass(dropdownMenu, 'show');
        }
        this.isShow = !this.isShow;
    }

}
```